# How do you get the size of a specific vector row in cpp?

Tags: c++, vector

I don't know why, but for some reason it won't work. Is there any other way to easily get the size of a row, this one doesn't seem to be very efficient.

```
vector< vector<string> >::iterator row;
vector<string>::iterator col;

for (row = vector.begin(); row != vector.end(); row++)
{

    std::ostringstream value;

    value << vector[*row].size(); //error 

    cout << "The length is" << value << endl;

    value.str("");
    value.clear();


}
```

> error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are
>   'std::vector > >' and
>   'std::vector >')
>            val << vec[*row].size();
>                      ^

Comment: You mean `row->size()`.

Comment: If you are doing something for the first time, such as using iterators, you should start with a very simple example to get a feel for the basics. Only then move on to more complex stuff.

Comment: Don't name your variable "vector".

Comment: Think of it as a vector of vectors, not a 2D matrix with rows and columns. There is no magic. A vector of vectors simply contains vectors. If you want to know the size of one of those, think of how you would find out the size of a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are you in wrong way iterators.. by the way, change:

```
value << vector[*row].size();
```

with:

```
value << *row.size();
/* or value << row->size(); */
```

As regards your question, take a look at this example:

```
typedef vector<vector<string>> Matrix;
/* specific index */ 
const int index = 3; 
Matrix matrix;
Matrix::iterator row = matrix.begin() + index;
cout << row->size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of an iterator as a kind of generalized pointer.  A general rule is that, if your iterator `it` is `vector<X>::iterator`, then `*it` is an `X&`.

As you have written in your program, the type of `row` is a `vector<vector<string>>::iterator`.  This means that `*row` is a `vector<string>&`, and you can call its `size()` function: either by `(*row).size()` or more simply `row->size()`.